# How to play a segment of a Lottie Animation (.json file ) in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, lottie

I want to play only a segment of the animation in react native using lottie view
the length is about 5 seconds while in speed={1} I wanna play only the first 3 seconds and then go to the next screen
the code is down below

LogoScreen.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Image, TextInput, StatusBar, Text } from "react-native";
import Icons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import LottieView from "lottie-react-native";

export default class ChatScreen extends React.Component {

  onAnimationFinish = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Login")
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" backgroundColor="#161f3d" />
        <View>
          <LottieView
            source={require('../assets/animations/lottie/MotionCorpse-Jrcanest.json')}
            style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignSelf: "center", height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
            autoPlay
            loop={false}
            speed={1}
            onAnimationFinish={this.onAnimationFinish}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you can do it by several ways, one of the way would be like below.

You can use ref to play it manually and then after 3 seconds just redirect to next screen.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Image, TextInput, StatusBar, Text } from "react-native";
import Icons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import LottieView from "lottie-react-native";

export default class ChatScreen extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.anim.play();

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate("Login")
        }, 3000);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" backgroundColor="#161f3d" />
                <View>
                    <LottieView
                        source={require('../assets/animations/lottie/MotionCorpse-Jrcanest.json')}
                        style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignSelf: "center", height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
                        autoPlay={false}
                        loop={false}
                        speed={1}
                        ref={animation => { this.anim = animation; }} 
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Another way is if you know exact frame numbers then you can play animation till that frame which completes at 3 seconds. It is already mentioned in Lottie documentation.

```
this.animation.play(30, 120);
```

Comment: @NeetinSolanki Is there a way to play certain frames on a loop? Like adding the `loop` prop but only with certain frame ranges?